# Pentaho CE 5.0 bi server set publish password

Tags: pentaho

I was used pentaho bi server CE 4.0.1 and for publishing metadata xmi file I was set publisher password in `biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/publisher_config.xml` file but, when I was move to pentaho CE 5.0 bi server I din't found any publisher_config.xml file in system folder. Can any one knows where to set publisher password in pentaho CE 5.0 bi server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to upload the xmi file in PUC and it will be published.